# mysql issue using join from a json string to get one unique value

Tags: mysql, json, join

I'm trying to produce a single query and really really stuck on how to set this using mysql.

I have one table **tblListings**

```
----------------------------------------------
| id | name |  photo_order                    |
----------------------------------------------
| 1  | mike | ["119","122","118","120","121"] |
| 2  | john | ["123"]                         |
| 3  | bill |                                 |
----------------------------------------------
```

and a second table **tblImages** for photos like this

```
----------------------------------------------
| id | listing_id |  image_name              |
----------------------------------------------
| 1  | 119        | image1.jpg               |
| 2  | 122        | image2.jpg               |
| 3  | 123        | image3.jpg               |
| x  | xxx        | xxxxxetc.jpg             |
----------------------------------------------
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to select all records from tblListings and then join it with a single matching image name (1 result) from the initial value of "photo_order" json array.  I believe this would be using join, but I am very confused on how to accomplish this.

For example, for record id 1 it would return tblListings.id = 1, name = mike, then because photo_order first value is 119 it would select record with listing_id of 119 from tblImages and join it to the result.

The end result of the initial row would be:

```
tblrecords.id  |  name | image_name |
-------------------------------------
 1             | mike  | image1.jpg |
```

I know this is something I could play with in PHP but the output is giving me trouble and it would be best to do this with mysql.

Very confused and totally out of ideas, please help if possible.

Comment: I have found that using json to store relational values is just as good as creating a table for this.  If you think otherwise do let me know why...  I'm open to ideas

Answer (score 0):

Work with strings inside MySQL is not always the best solution for performance.

But if you can't change your database structure or your application, or even if you don't care about execution time, you can do the following:

```
SELECT 
  i.*
FROM tblImages i JOIN (
  SELECT
    id,
    TRIM(LEADING '["' FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(photo_order, '"', 2)) AS image_id 
  FROM tblListings
) l ON i.listing_id = l.image_id;
```

The trick is here: `TRIM(LEADING '["' FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(photo_order, '"', 2))`. With this you start getting everything before the second `"`, that is `["119` for instance. And then trims the `["` from beginning. Finally you can use the remaining number in the joining condition.

Comment: If I was to change the database structure, and add another table (or column) what do you suggest I move it to?  Would you suggest adding an "order" column int value onto this tblImages?  What would be the best for performance if building a highly traffic application? Thanks I greatly appreciate the feedback!

Comment: @GregParker yes, what you said is a good approach. Add a numeric column probably will solve your need to store the images ordering. To increase performance within your queries you can create an index over your `order` column.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first number to match, you can do a join like this:

```
select i.*
from tbllistings l join
     tblimages i
     on l.photo_order = concat('[", i.listing_id, '"%');
```

That said, you should not be storing lists of ids in a JSON array.  These should be stored in a proper junction table.

Comment: If I was to change the database structure, and add another table (or column) what do you suggest I move it to? Would you suggest adding an "order" column int value onto this tblImages? What would be the best for performance if building a highly traffic application? Thanks I greatly appreciate the feedback!

Comment: @GregParker . . . I'm not opposed to "nested tables" as this construct is sometimes called.  But, you should use a database such as Postgres or Oracle that supports them better.  In MySQL, you are best off with a junction table for the list of images and perhaps an additional column for the (single) id of a preferred image.